# Call App Initialization module in Azure Web Apps

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP .NET MVC 5 app in which I defined an initialization page in my `web.config` :

```
<applicationInitialization>
    <add initializationPage="/Cache/Index" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

This action generates the cache for the entire website but right now it is never called.

I would like this page to be called right after the deployment on the staging slot but not when I swap from stage to production.

How can I achieve that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> would like this page to be called right after the deployment on the staging slot but not when I swap from stage to production.

As we know, the Application Initialization Module will help warm up the application during the swap operation. If you’d like to let staging slot warm up without swapping from staging to production, you could try to create a dev slot and enable [Auto Swap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing#configure-auto-swap), and then you could publish application to dev slot, which will auto swap from dev to staging and make application warm up.

**Create dev and staging slots**

[image]

**Enable Auto Swap for dev slot**

[image]

Configures AppInit module

```
<system.webServer>
  <applicationInitialization>
    <add initializationPage="/Cache/Index.aspx" hostName="specify the host name to use for the warm up requests here" />
  </applicationInitialization>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion and added a new slot with auto swap. Unfortunately, the cache is partially generated on the dev slot and I got nothing in the cache on the stage slot. Any idea ?